# 3d plot of function with symbolic variables

Tags: matlab

I have a function with 2 symbolic variables which is very complicated and long. I want to have it plotted in a surface. The function looks like this:

```
  y^(1/2)*x - y^(1/2)*(x - 1)*((40*y^2 + 60*y^(1/2) - 60*y^(3/2) - 10)/(90*y^(1/2)) + ...
```

Whenever I try to plot, I get: "Undefined function 'plotfunc3d' for input arguments of type 'sym'" or "Conversion to double from sym is not possible".

How can I plot a surface? Thanks.

Comment: What command are you trying to use to plot this function? `surf`? Over what range? And your function isn't even complete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, you're trying to plot a symbolic equation using functions designed for Matlab's default floating-point datatypes. Your question is terse and you didn't even indicate how you're trying to plot the function in question, so I'll just give suggestions.

You have two options. You can use a plot function designed for symbolic math or you can substitute in floating point values for all of your parameters and values. Here is [a list of `ez-` plotting methods](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/plot-functions-and-data.html) that can be used for symbolic equations.

Secondly, you can use the [`subs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/subs.html) function to substitute in values, or vectors/matrices of values into a symbolic equation. You can also try using `double` if you end up with an equation that is stil symbolic but not in terms of any variables, e.g., `double(sym('pi'))`.

I can't really be more specific because your question wasn't, but you can also try Googling "Matlab plot symbolic function" for more results.

Comment: Another alternative is to do everything in [MuPAD](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/index.html#mupad) (type `mupad` in your command window). Here are [details on plotting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/mupad_ug/using-graphics.html) in Mupad.